# Unable to fetch all data from nested xml

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("D:\Parsed_CCD.xml")
doc = tree.getroot()


codeList=[]
codeSystemList=[]
codeSystemName=[]
displayName=[]
code=[]
codeS=[]
codeN=[]
display=[]
status=[]
stime=[]
etime=[]


for elem1 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/code'):
    codeList.append(elem1.text)

for elem2 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/codeSystem'):
    codeSystemList.append(elem2.text)


for elem3 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/codeSystemName'):
    codeSystemName.append(elem3.text)

for elem4 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/displayName'):
    displayName.append(elem4.text)  

for elem5 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/translation/code'):
    code.append(elem5.text) 

for elem6 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/translation/codeSystem'):
    codeS.append(elem6.text)    

for elem7 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/translation/codeSystemName'):
    codeN.append(elem7.text)

for elem9 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/productCode/translation/displayName'):
    display.append(elem9.text)  

for elem8 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/statusCode'):
    status.append(elem8.text)

for elem10 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/startTime'):
    stime.append(elem10.text)

for elem11 in doc.findall('.//medicationsInfo/entryInfo/endTime'):
    etime.append(elem11.text)


for i in range(len(codeList)):
    print (codeList[i],codeSystemList[i],codeSystemName[i],displayName[i],code[i],codeS[i],codeN[i],status[i],etime[i])
```

I need to print all values column-wise, but the problem is I am printing data column-wise, but I am not able to fetch all the data because I have a nested xml file and it has different number of values. The for loop is reaching only minimum number and the rest of the data is not displaying. Is it possible to use a different for loop like i and j, and append them both and display them?

Comment: Can you please show us the xml file also?

Comment: else how can print none in blank spaces?

Comment: it is very huge..

Comment: for example, in productCode i have 10 code and 8 codeSystem, how can i print them column wise using above logic. please help me.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: i have added sample xml file.

Comment: From your question i am assuming you are facing issue while printing the data

Comment: yes, but i am not able print all data. in above xml i have two product code and one routecode, using my logic i am able to print only one, so i want to use two for loop one for productcode and one for routecode and join them print together in column wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) function this it will insert None in blank spaces and should solve your problem

`rows=list(itertools.izip_longest(codeList,codeSystemList,codeSystemName,displayName,code,codeS,codeN,status,etime))
for row in rows:
   print(row)`

Comment: first four column i am getting as none.

Comment: code, codes... they are again nested below codeList, codeSystemList....

Comment: code, codes... are sub-tags under <translation> tag, in the above xml file.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve,code will take the elements from each list and form a new list if the number of elements in a list are less it will pad "None" while creating the list which is why you are seeing none, If the first four columns are entirely none that means those list did not have any value, You can print the entire list and see if they have the data

Comment: First make sure that with findAll you have parsed the xml as per your need. The code mentioned above takes care of displaying the data

Comment: thank you @Optimus for your reply, actually consider the above xml file, i am able to print all data under routeCode and ProductCode, but if i try to print data from sub-tags under <translation> tag, then i will get value as none, but same time i am able to print data from translation tag.

Comment: here, can i use two for loop and join them and will print joined result? is that possible?

Comment: yep.. its working very well, meeting my requirements.